# Solving the logistic equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logistic-regression

I need to solve the logistic equation

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = P(a-b\ln P)$$

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: $\mathrm d P=\frac1{-b}\mathrm d (a-bP)$.

Comment: @Vim corrected it.

Comment: This is a seperable DE. This problem is only as difficult as the integral.

Comment: @Kaynex Then you and I find integrals very different.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=P(a-b\ln P)$$
$$\int\frac1{P(a-b\ln P)}\ dP = \int1\ dt=t+K_1$$
The derivative of $\ln(a-b\ln P)$ with respect to $P$ is $\frac{-b}{P(a-b\ln P)}$, so:
$$\int\frac1{P(a-b\ln P)}\ dP =-\frac1b\ln(a-b\ln P)+K_2=t+K_1$$
$$-\frac1b\ln(a-b\ln P)=t+K_3$$
$$\ln(a-b\ln P)=-bt+K_4$$
$$a-b\ln P=e^{-bt+K_4}=A_1e^{-bt}$$
$$\ln P=\frac{a-A_1e^{-bt}}b=\frac ab-Ae^{-bt}$$

> $$P=e^{\frac ab-Ae^{-bt}}$$

where $A$ is a constant.